# Add variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am preparing a cart where the pricing derives from the number of items selected in menu. I am using javascript to calculate price on the same page.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var coffee = document.forms[0];
  var txt = 0;
  var i;


  for (i = 0; i < coffee.length; i++) {
    if (coffee[i].checked) {
      txt = txt++;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("order").value = txt;
}
```

```html
<label> Select the project category you will like to float </label>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Web Development
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">App Development
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">SEO Ninja
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">The Social media geek
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Design Wizard
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">The contest of Content
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Marketing Marathon
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Recruitment Hackathon
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Add to cart">
<input type="text" id="order" size="50">
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <ul class="actions">
      <input type="submit" name="submit3" value="Register">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Can somebody help me return an integer value (= no. of items checked) with txt.

Comment: Do you have more than one form on the page?  `alert($("form").length)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `txt = txt++;` you are replacing the next value with the old value.  You need to use just `txt++`. Also, I think it's better if you give an id to the form to make sure that you are targetting the right form because ids are/must unique. See the working snippets below please:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var coffee = document.getElementById('cart_form');
  var txt = 0;
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < coffee.length; i++) {
    if (coffee[i].checked) {
      txt++;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("order").value = txt;
}
```

```html
<form method='post' action='' id='cart_form'>
  <label> Select the project category you will like to float </label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="3">Web Development
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">App Development
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">SEO Ninja
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">The Social media geek
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Design Wizard
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">The contest of Content
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Marketing Marathon
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Recruitment Hackathon
  </div>

  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Add to cart">
  <input type="text" id="order" size="50">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <ul class="actions">
        <input type="submit" name="submit3" value="Register">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

As you can see I've also added a opening tag for the `form` element.

You can run the working snippet from here or you can take a look **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hvvzhLb6/)** to test it if you want.

An alternative without the old `onclick` would be too use `addEventListener` for the click like this:

```js
document.getElementById("add_to_cart").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var coffee = document.getElementById('cart_form');
  var txt = 0;
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < coffee.length; i++) {
    if (coffee[i].checked) {
      txt++;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("order").value = txt;
});
```

```html
<form method='post' action='' id='cart_form'>
  <label> Select the project category you will like to float </label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="3">Web Development
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">App Development
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">SEO Ninja
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">The Social media geek
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Design Wizard
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">The contest of Content
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Marketing Marathon
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Recruitment Hackathon
  </div>

  <input type="button" id='add_to_cart' value="Add to cart">
  <input type="text" id="order" size="50">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <ul class="actions">
        <input type="submit" name="submit3" value="Register">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I've seen you tagged this as `jQuery` too. Here's an alternative using `$(":checkbox:checked").length`:

```js
$('#add_to_cart').on('click', function(){
  $('#order').val($("#cart_form :checkbox:checked").length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method='post' action='' id='cart_form'>
  <label> Select the project category you will like to float </label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="3">Web Development
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">App Development
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">SEO Ninja
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">The Social media geek
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Design Wizard
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">The contest of Content
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Marketing Marathon
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Recruitment Hackathon
  </div>

  <input type="button" id='add_to_cart' value="Add to cart">
  <input type="text" id="order" size="50">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <ul class="actions">
        <input type="submit" name="submit3" value="Register">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @lonut Tried this. It still returns 0

Comment: @ZigsawConsultancy did you try the snippet?  it works there, so you must have done something else.  Can you elaborate on what you've done?

Comment: @ZigsawConsultancy try `txt+=1`

Comment: @ZigsawConsultancy, as someone already said above try and run the snippet, you can see it works. Maybe there is another issue in your code. Can't replicate with the code you provided.

Comment: Just a pointer, you can achieve same result(`:checked`) without jQuery as well

Comment: @Rajesh, yes, agree. I already knew that. I just wanted to make a `jQuery` snippet that replicates somehow the `JS` one. I hope it helps the OP.

Comment: @ZigsawConsultancy, and the answer you accepted does work? I don't see any difference between my answer and that answer. Maybe except the use of `document.getElementsByName('coffee');` instead of `document.getElementById('cart_form');` But that should not be a problem.

Comment: @lonut, probably something to do with getelementbyname & getelementbyid

Comment: @ZigsawConsultancy, Have you added the id to the form? Do you have multiple same ids on the same page? That could cause not to work. You just need to check your console for errors. Doesn't work it can mean numerous things...

Comment: @lonut: Yes, added the ID but I had missed the 2nd getelementbyID. 
Works like a charm :) Thanks. Answer accepted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137135/discussion-between-ionut-and-zigsaw-consultancy).

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a loop just to count number of checkboxes checked.

You can look into `querySelectorAll` and get only selected checkboxes. Now you just have to check for `.length` and you have `txt` value.

```
var txt = document.querySelectorAll('#frm1 input[name="coffee"]:checked').length;
```

**Note:** I have added `id` attribute to `form` tag to uniquely get checkboxes.

**Sample Code**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var txt = document.querySelectorAll('#frm1 input[name="coffee"]:checked').length;
  document.getElementById("order").value = txt;
}
```

```html
<form id="frm1" method='post' action=''>
  <label> Select the project category you will like to float </label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="3">Web Development
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">App Development
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">SEO Ninja
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">The Social media geek
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Design Wizard
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">The contest of Content
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Marketing Marathon
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Recruitment Hackathon
  </div>

  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Add to cart">
  <input type="text" id="order" size="50">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <ul class="actions">
        <input type="submit" name="submit3" value="Register">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to replace `txt = txt++` with just `txt++` or `txt = txt + 1`

I also recommend you to use `document.getElementsByName('coffee');`

Beacuse this guarantees that in the future if you add another input for another purpose, you won't need to change this function.

```js
function myFunction() {
var coffee = document.getElementsByName('coffee');
var txt = 0;
var i;


for (i = 0; i < coffee.length; i++) { 
    if (coffee[i].checked) {
        txt++;
    }
}
document.getElementById("order").value = txt;
}
```

```html
<label> Select the project category you will like to float </label>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Web Development 
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">App Development 
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">SEO Ninja  
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">The Social media geek
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Design Wizard 
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">The contest of Content 
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Marketing Marathon 
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="1">Recruitment Hackathon 
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Add to cart">
<input type="text" id="order" size="50">
```

Comment: Needs an explanation

Comment: @freedomn-m I always save the post after inserting a snippet, then edit the post for description:)

Comment: @Rajesh i do this just to make safe the code in the snippet

Comment: @er-han I get that. That's why I did not downvote. But that can attract downvotes. Also FYI, SO syncs content of your answer. Try to partially type answer and refresh page. :-)

Comment: Also being a bit cynical, using `getElementsByClassName` is not right. You can have multiple forms having different types/vendors' coffee. You should always try to use a composite selector. `parent + child` to uniquely identify elements. You can check my answer for more info

Comment: @er-han you might like to add "edit in progress" then as it's not possible to tell if you're adding details or have left it a code-only answer.  *you* might "always" do that, but many people don't and I'm not going to try and remember who does and who doesn't...

Comment: @er-han Thanks :) Solved